# Get Actual Memory usage of a process using process id

Tags: java, memory

I used below linux command for get the actual memory usage of a process using process id.

```
pmap -x pid | grep total
```

But it did't give the correct memory allocation size of a process. When I used below code in my java code, it gives the correct memory allocation size of the java process.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.gc();
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
```

How to get the correct memory allocation size of a java process using pid?

Comment: Why do you think the first number is incorrect?

Comment: I used java code for get the out of Memory error. I execute that code in tomcat server and get the error. Then I get the pid of that process and run first command and get these three values. ( 3422472  712208  694980).  I get the last kilobyte value(694980) of these three and convert into MB (nearly 694Mb). After this I increase the heap size(1024Mb) of the server and run again the code. Issue is not solved. When I run the second code it display  1041Mb is the process memory size. When I increase heap size to 2048Mb, it works fine.

Comment: @assylias please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool `jconsole` from the JDK to view memory allocation of a running Java program in realtime.